# How can I ensure ImageSource is not disposed

Tags: c#, xamarin, imagesource, objectdisposedexception

I have a function in my Xamarin.Forms app. I'm currently pushing the app to the latest version of all dependancies in preparation for MAUI migration.

The functions purpose is to gather all of the conversations for the messenger section of the app (simplified into a function to reduce Firebase calls as the list is used in two places of the app). What I am finding is that by the time the list is loaded into the `ListView` on the page, the `ImageSource` elements within the `List<>` have been disposed by the GC (I'm assuming because the app has left the scope of the function so it's contents including it's return value is scrapped but i'm not sure).

How can I get this working? It worked in the previous version of `Xamarin.Forms` and `.NET` but me thinks I need to improve it's efficiency as the effectiveness of the GC must have been improved in the newer versions.

The function in question:

```cs
public static async void GetConversations()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ran!");
            IQuerySnapshot conversations = await App.Firestore.Collection("conversations").WhereEqualsTo("Members." + App.Authentication.CurrentUser.Uid, true).GetAsync();
            foreach (IDocumentSnapshot doc in conversations.Documents)
            {
                Conversation convo = doc.ToObject<Conversation>();
                convo.GetLatests(doc.Id);
                string uid = convo.Members.Keys.Where(x => !x.Contains(App.Authentication.CurrentUser.Uid)).First();
                ImageSource profile = await ImageHandle.GetProfileImage(uid);
                ConversationsList.Add(new KeyValuePair<Conversation, ImageSource>(convo, profile));
            }
            ConversationsReady?.Invoke(ConversationsList, new EventArgs());
        }
```

And the `GetProfileImage()` function of `ImageHandle`:

```cs
public static async Task<ImageSource> GetProfileImage(string userID)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.Stream imageStream = await App.FirebaseStorage.GetInstanceFromUrl("gs://av_profile_images").RootReference.Child(userID + "_1080x1080.jpeg").GetStreamAsync();
                return ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageStream);
            }
            catch (FirebaseStorageException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to get profile image!");
                App.Crashlytics.LogError(e, "Failed to get profile image");
                return ImageSource.FromFile("ProfilePlaceholder");
            }
        }
```

And finally the exception (two part):

```
[OpenGLRenderer] --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'ImageHandle.cs:53,1' to void AV.Resources.Extensions.ImageHandle.<GetPostImage>d__2.MoveNext () [0x0011f].
[istsandvenue.AV] Attempt to remove index outside index area (0 vs 1-1)
[istsandvenue.AV] JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x19) failed to find entry
[istsandvenue.AV]   at mono.android.runtime.InputStreamAdapter.n_read(Native method)
[istsandvenue.AV]   at mono.android.runtime.InputStreamAdapter.read(InputStreamAdapter.java:57)
[istsandvenue.AV]   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native method)
[istsandvenue.AV]   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:791)
[istsandvenue.AV]   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:766)
[istsandvenue.AV]   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:807)
Image loading: Image load failed: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureNotClosed () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs:121 
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x0004e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs:369 
  at Android.Runtime.InputStreamAdapter.Read (System.Byte[] bytes, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 length) [0x00000] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/InputStreamAdapter.cs:38 
  at Java.IO.InputStream.n_Read_arrayBII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_b, System.Int32 off, System.Int32 len) [0x0001f] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Java.IO.InputStream.cs:274 
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLII_I (_JniMarshal_PPLII_I callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0, System.Int32 p1, System.Int32 p2) [0x00005] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:264 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLII_I(intptr,intptr,intptr,int,int)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_static_object_method_a(intptr,intptr&,intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0003f] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12886 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00008] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:151 
  at Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (System.IO.Stream is) [0x0001f] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.cs:835 
  at Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory+<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<DecodeStreamAsync>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.cs:845 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.StreamImagesourceHandler.LoadImageAsync (Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource imagesource, Android.Content.Context context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancelationToken) [0x000da] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\StreamImagesourceHandler.cs:19 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ResourceManager.GetFormsBitmapAsync (Android.Content.Context context, Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource imageSource, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0006d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\ResourceManager.cs:152 
ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource
```

After this error the app carries on for a few more lines and then crashes when the debugger catches up providing only:
`[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xb83cd000000008 in tid 12022 (istsandvenue.AV), pid 12022 (istsandvenue.AV)`

I'm a complete noob when it comes to diagnosing issues when the compiler doesn't give me direction so I'm assuming the fatal interrupt in connection between the debugger and the app instance is due to the most recent error that i've provided above but again - this is only an assumption i'm not certain.

Many Thanks in advance,

Matthew

Comment: The string of messages seems to imply there is a problem with the "data"; the issue being either "data corruption"; or, it's related to your "upgrade/ conversion"; and it's a compatibility issue.

Comment: I haven't begun my conversion yet. Only upgrades currently. I have found that when  I remove my messages page from the app it runs with no issues so the issue is caused by the messenger/menu pages fighting over `App.Conversationslist`

Comment: According to the error message, it seems the `ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageStream)` is invalid image soruce.

Comment: I understand this, how can I amend the above to get this working is my question?

Comment: But can't make sure the problem is this line or not. Did you try to set the Image control's source such as `image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageStream)` to check it?

Comment: I'll try that now. Essentially the above code works like an API for two different sections in the app. When the conversations gatherer runs, it calls the second function which returns an ImageSource that is added to the `ConversationsList` which is a list of `Conversation` objects. These are then binded directly to a `StackLayout` using the `ItemsSource` extension - somewhere during this process, the `ImageSource` is being disposed off (I assume) leading to the source being `null` by the time it's mapped to the view causing the crash

Comment: It's an Android-only issue. A bizarre thing is that it crashes like this every time until I removed the Messenger page from the app (one of the two pages that share this function). Now it sometimes happens, sometimes doesn't. The other image services work in the app, it's just this one. The only difference in them is that this data is collected from Firebase once at app run and then accessed whenever the app needs it to save on the amount of chargeable requests going off to Firebase